# For an array in Dafny whats the difference between old(a[0]) and old(a)[0]

Tags: dafny

For an array in Dafny, what's the difference between `old(a[0])` and `old(a)[0]`?

A method modifies an array 'a' by adding 1 to the first element. At the conclusion of the method, what is the value of `old(a[0])` and `old(a)[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! Yes, they are different.

When an expression is evaluated inside an `old`, all of its *heap dereferences* refer to the heap at the beginning of the method. Anything that is not a heap dereference is not affected at all by `old`.

In your example `a[0]` is a heap dereference, so `old(a[0])` gets the 0-th value of the array "pointed to" by `a` in the old heap.

However, `a` by itself is not a heap dereference, it's just a parameter to the local function whose value never changes. So `old(a) == a`. One way to think about this is that `a` stores the "address" of the array, and that address doesn't change over the lifetime of the method.

Now that we know `old(a) == a`, it follows that `old(a)[0] == a[0]`. In other words, the `old` has no effect in your second example.

Here is a small example to demonstrate:

```
method M(a: array<int>)
  requires a.Length >= 2
  requires a[0] == 1
  modifies a
  ensures a[1] == old(a[0])  // so far so good
  ensures old(a) == a        // perhaps surprising: Dafny proves this!
  ensures a[1] == old(a)[0]  // but this is not necessarily true, 
                             // because old(a)[0] actually means the same thing as a[0]
{
  a[1] := 1;
}
```

Comment: See also the following Dafny Power User note: http://leino.science/papers/krml273.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation! I appreciate it.