# Ensure that a map didn't change?

Tags: dafny

In the following code, all 4 times that `old()` appears, it triggers this warning:
`Argument to 'old' does not dereference the mutable heap, so this use of 'old' has no effect`.

<del>(Additionally, according to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64628903/for-an-array-in-dafny-whats-the-difference-between-olda0-and-olda0),
`ensures m == old(m)` would always be useless because a map is a value type)</del> **EDIT: `ensures mymap == old(mymap)` does work in methods. Makes sense when mymap is a field in the containing class.**

`Unchanged()` doesn't work with maps either. So I've run out of ideas. How can one `ensure` that a map didn't change?

```
trait A {
    var b : nat
}

lemma oldDict(m: map<A, nat>)
    ensures m == old(m)
    ensures m.Items == old(m.Items)
    ensures forall k :: k in (m.Keys + old(m.Keys)) ==> m[k] == old(m[k])
    {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it mentions it is a value type, it won't change if you return the same map. You have to create another map to create a map that is not equal to the original. When you do an update to a map like `m[k := v]` you are actually creating a new map which you must reassign to a variable otherwise the change will not be preserved.
https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-maps

Also to write lemmas about frames you need to use a twostate lemma. There aren't many examples but the blog has some good examples [here](https://dafny.org/blog/2023/10/11/insertion-sort/).